# Проблема с аддоном FLIP fluids blender

Tags: 3d, blender

У меня возникла проблема с аддоном FLIP fluids в blender, проблема в том что жидкость не видит припятствие и протикает сквозь него, подскажите что делать пожалуйста.
Вот видео https://youtu.be/NAz-k7XCuFg